# Accessing file outside of Glassfish

Tags: xml, rest, glassfish

I've created an xml file using a REST web service (which isn't located in glassfish) and I then need a php file located within quercus inside of glassfish to be able to access this file to modify it. However I can't copy the file into glassfish because it's protected and I can't seem to access any files outside of glassfish from within.

There's a lot of talk about using alternate document roots (eg. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266608/how-to-provide-access-to-an-external-resource-file-for-a-glassfish-web-applica) or  [this document](https://blogs.oracle.com/jluehe/entry/alternate_docroots_in_web_applications)) but I can't find how to implement this. They all say to find either a `sun-web.xml` file or `glassfish-web.xml` file and edit that but I have neither of those in my glassfish server. I've also tried doing it through the web interface like this [website](http://www.marceble.com/2009/07/virtual-directories-in-glassfish/) but that doesnt' work either.

Does anyone else know what I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glassfish-web.xml` (previously known as `sun-web.xml`) should be  placed into `WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` of your web-application's .war file. That is why you can't locate it when browsing the server directories.

Configuring alternate docroots enables your application to serve files from other locations.

Ill add an example of the file just in case, but this part you probably already know

```
<glassfish-web-app ...>
    ...
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/my.jpg dir=/srv/images/jpg"/>
    <property name="alternatedocroot_2" value="from=*.jpg dir=/srv/images/jpg"/>
    <property name="alternatedocroot_3" value="from=/jpg/* dir=/src/images"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Look into the extended doc:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beaft.html#geqpl